# List monad: difference between `>>=` and `return` behaviors

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm just getting started on monads, and I can't figure out why these two expressions evaluate differently:

```
ghci> [1,2] >>= \n -> ['a','b'] >>= \ch -> return (n,ch)
[(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(2,'b')]


ghci> return ([1,2],['a','b'])
([1,2],"ab")
```

Comment: You might gain some insight if you explain why you think they should be the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The types are different, so it's reasonable that the behaviors are different

The first expression would typecheck as `Num t => [(t, Char)]`

The use of [] as the monad in the (>>=) means that it infers that the monad should be the List monad and in the context of the `List Monad` http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/List (>>=) is concatMap and return is (:[]).

```
[1,2] >>= \n -> ['a','b'] >>= \ch -> return (n,ch)
```

is the same as

```
concatMap (\n -> concatMap (\ch -> [(n, ch)]) ['a', 'b']) [1,2]
```

which returns `[(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(2,'b')]`

In your second example what's really going on is

that the type of the expression is a bit more general:

```
Prelude> :t return ([1,2],['a','b'])
return ([1,2],['a','b']) :: (Monad m, Num t) => m ([t], [Char])
```

Because you're running it in GHCi a few things happen. GHCi can be considered a very big special IO Monad. So since no monad was specified, when GHC tries to print the results, it'll take the `m` Monad to be `IO` in this case.

The `t` is defaulted to `Integer` as well, so the type of the resulting expression is `:: IO ([Integer], [Char])`.

As it happens, all the types used have a `Show` instance, so GHC can print the results of executing the `IO` action, which in this case (due to the action being return) is the same as the input.

Answer (score 6):

In GHCi, you can interactively check the type of an expression using `:t`.  Doing so shows that your expressions have different types:

```
ghci> :t [1,2] >>= \n -> ['a','b'] >>= \ch -> return (n,ch)
[1,2] >>= \n -> ['a','b'] >>= \ch -> return (n,ch)
  :: (Num t) => [(t, Char)]

ghci> :t return ([1,2],['a','b'])
return ([1,2],['a','b']) :: (Num t, Monad m) => m ([t], [Char])
```

Thus, they have different values.

Perhaps you're confused by the presence of monads *inside* the argument to `return`.  However, look at its type:

```
ghci> :t return
return :: Monad m => a -> m a
```

`return` knows nothing about its argument -- it just takes a value, any value, and places it in a default, monadic context.

---

To understand exactly what happens when these expressions are evaluated, you'll need:

1. Hoogle, to find the monad instance for lists, and
2. a more specific type for the second expression

[Here's](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Base.html#Monad) the monad instance:

```
instance  Monad []  where
    m >>= k             = foldr ((++) . k) [] m
    m >> k              = foldr ((++) . (\ _ -> k)) [] m
    return x            = [x]
    fail _              = []
```

(We can ignore `>>` and `fail`, since we're not using them.)

So let's expand our expression:

```
[1,2] >>= \n -> ['a','b'] >>= \ch -> return (n,ch)
```

so setting `m = [1, 2]` and `k = \n -> ['a','b'] >>= \ch -> return (n,ch)` we get:

```
foldr ((++) . (\n -> ['a','b'] >>= \ch -> return (n,ch))) [] [1,2]
```

now to get rid of the second `>>=`, `m = ['a', 'b']` and `k = \ch -> return (n, ch)`:

```
foldr ((++) . (\n -> rest)) [] [1,2]
  where
    rest = foldr ((++) . (\ch -> return (n,ch))) [] ['a', 'b']
```

and `return` is easy to get rid of:

```
foldr ((++) . (\n -> rest)) [] [1,2]
  where
    rest = foldr ((++) . (\ch -> [(n,ch)]) [] ['a', 'b']
```

On the other hand, the value of the 2nd expression:

```
return ([1,2],['a','b'])
```

depends on *which monad you're in*.  In the list monad, it simply becomes:

```
[([1,2], ['a','b'])] :: [] ([Int], String)
```

whereas in the Maybe monad, it's:

```
Just ([1,2], ['a', 'b']) :: Maybe ([Int], String)
```

Comment: This is really helpful; if I could mark a second favorite answer, I definitely would.